# Replacing a parent with its child in XSLT

Tags: xslt, parent-child

I wish to use XSLT to make following change. Delete parent and move its children 1 level up.

Input is:

```
<data>
     <parentnode>
                <results>
                        <result>
                </results>
     </parentnode>
     <parentnode>
                <results>
                        <result>
                        <result>
                </results>
     </parentnode>
</data>
```

Expected Output is:

```
<data>
     <parentnode>
                <result>
     </parentnode>
     <parentnode>
                <result>
                <result>
     </parentnode>
</data>
```

Instead of that, my output comes out to be:

```
<data>
     <parentnode>
                <result>
                <result>
                <result>
     </parentnode>
     <parentnode>
                <result>
                <result>
                <result>
     </parentnode>
</data>
```

I am using following xslt code:

```
    <!-- Identity Template -->
    
    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- Move results up one node -->
    
    <xsl:template match="results">
        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: I have run your code on given input and found that output is same as expected output https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVhEaj4

Comment: Thank you. It is somehow not working for my structure. My structure starts with a root results tag as well and on the XSLT fiddle, it is only removing root tag. rest all structure remains the same. other results are not moved to the parent position. in eclipse, XSLT keeps the root results tag and works on all the internal tags moving them to parent. but it also copies out of scope results nodes everywhere.